# jquery cycle - keeping slideshow centred even if images are wider than browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to use the jquery cycle plugin to fade in and out some images which I want to use on the front page of my site.

The trouble is, to cater for people with big screens the images are 1400px wide and centred, which works well on large screen sizes, but I need these images to be centred on all screen sizes and if you look at it through a smaller viewing portal the very left of the image is always viewable. I'd like the centre of the image to be in the center of the viewing portal all the time.

To better explain if you visit:
http://renegadeox.com/
and resize your browser window (assuming you have a resolution over 1400px wide) you can see that the image stays centered until the window is smaller than the image, at which point the right hand side starts to get invisable. I want both sides to get cropped at the same rate.

I know it's possible with a background image. But I can't fade a background image.

I've seen other ways of centering images and fading etc but none working together. Can anyone help me out. I'm out of ideas :(

here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slideshowWrap').cycle({
            fx: 'fade', // http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/ Background rotater
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto" class="slideshowWrap">
        <div class="homeslideshow">
            <img src="background_01.jpg" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="homeslideshow">
            <img src="background_02.jpg" alt="" />    
        </div>
        <div class="homeslideshow">
            <img src="background_03.jpg" alt="" />    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Images can be centered by setting their css to {display:block;margin:0 auto} or setting the image to {display:inline} and setting the images parent element to {text-align:center}

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch That doesn't work if the image is wider than its container.

Comment: You could use javascript to move the image left relative to the container. You would move it half the images width to the left

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch - that sounds encouraging but I'm not completely sure what you mean. I need to do a bit more reading about javascript, can you elaborate?

Comment: I tried to make a little JavaScript Fiddle for you however i'm at work and cannot spare the time. If no body has replied later, i will help you out buddy

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch - Hi dude. I hope this isn't cheeky to as but I'm still trying to get a solution to this. I was just wondering if you had a little free time in work today if you could give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Go through and give each image the class: "sliderImage".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slideshowWrap').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', // http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/ Background rotater
    });
    centerSliderImage();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    centerSliderImage();
});

function centerSliderImage() {
    $(".sliderImage").each(function () {
        if (this.width > window.innerWidth) {
            var offset = (this.width - window.innerWidth) / 2;
            $(this).css({
                "margin-left": "-" + offset + "px"
            })
        }
    })
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wy2ku/6/

Easier to see demo:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Wy2ku/6/show/